# Recover Data after windows installation

Tags: data-recovery

to sum it up :
Is it possible to recover data after:
deleting partitions>recreating 1 partition as GPT> installing windows?

here is in details:
Accidentally I installed win 11 on the HDD while I thought I was installing in the new (SSD) I just bought.
While installation I have deleted both E & F partitions, then I created one partitions and the installation of windows convert the HDD to GPT.
I tried lots of recovery Application and I've tried the recovery in Win Mini PE with no luck.
I have not used The HDD after installation has completed, Is there any granted idea to recover?
Thanks.

Comment: More specific: https://superuser.com/a/1758086/705502

Comment: Use a Recovery Agency.